# Problem reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04 (plus can't fix broken packages)

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, reinstall

I have 2 major problems:

When I open Synaptic, it says that the package `linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic` is broken. I tried to fix it using the button **Fix broken packages** and removing it. But it gives me this message:

```
E: linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic: installed linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1``
```

I tried some console commands seen in other answers but they did not work:

```
$ sudo apt install -f 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

After that I decided to reinstall Ubuntu. But the desktop icons seem to not work when I double-click or right click-> open. Because of that I cannot open the Ubuntu LiveUSB.

The point is:

that broken package does not allow me to install or uninstall anything and due to the fact that I cannot open desktop icons I really don't know what to do.

I have tried every guide but I have not succeeded yet.

Sorry for the confusion but I am totally new in linux.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you please rephrase you question because it's very confusing and not clear, what it is that you are trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: @StrabagISS_Krall i'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu.The desktop icons are not working and i don't know how to open the liveUsb installation program(which i found only in the desktop)because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have other kernels installed by commands output:

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep '/boot/vmlinuz-'
dpkg --list | grep linux-image | grep ii
ls /boot | grep vmlinuz
```

Check also your current running kernel:

```
uname -a
```

If there's a kernel you could boot from alongside with broken package kernel, you could try this command:

```
sudo apt purge linux-*5.3.0-26-*
```